# ¿Cómo redimensionar una imagen con imagemagick conservando las proporciones?

Tags: bash

Estoy haciendo un script de bash que redimensione todas las imágenes de un directorio conservando las proporciones de la imagen original. Todas las imágenes tienen valores diferentes para ancho y alto, por lo que no puedo utilizar algo como esto:

```
for i in *.png
do
    echo "Convirtiendo $i..."
    convert "$i" -resize $ancho $largo "${i%.*}_.png"
done
```

En la documentación de imagemagick encontré que la propiedad `xheight` podría funcionar para lo que quiero hacer, pero no comprendo cómo pasar ese parámetro en el programa. [Aquí encontré esa información](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry)

Mi objetivo es tener algo como esto:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Introduce la altura de la imagen"
read h
for i in *.png
do
    echo "Convirtiendo $i..."
    # Comando para redimensionar la imagen utilizando $h para su altura
    # y que el ancho de la imagen se ajuste de manera automática.
done
```

Estos son los comandos que he intentado hasta ahora:

- `convert "$i" xheight $h "{$i%*}_.png"`
- `convert "$i" -resize xheight $h "{$i%*}_.png"`
- `convert "$i" -resize -xheight $h "{$i%*}_.png"`

Comment: Así funciona, ¿qué no? La misma documentación que enlazas lo dice: _Cuando se proporciona el ancho, la altura se se selecciona automágicamente para preservar el aspecto_...

Comment: No, ya probé de varias maneras y no consigo que funcione el script. Siempre me da algún tipo de error porque no estoy usando el parámetro de manera correcta.

Comment: Para no quitarte tu tiempo, presentándote alternativas que ya probaste que no funcionan, deberías indicar __qué has intentado__ y que tipo de errores obtienes. Te recomiendo que sigas esta guía [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución y este es el script completo.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

mensajes(){
    ok=true
    echo "¿Qué quieres cambiar: (w)idth o (h)eight ?"
    read set
    if ( [ $set == 'w' ] || [ $set == 'W' ] ); then
        set='W'
    elif ( [ $set == 'h' ] || [ $set == 'H' ] ); then
        set='H'
    else
        ok=false
    fi
    if [ "$ok" == true ]; then
        echo "Ingresa un valor "
        read pixel
        resize "!@"
    else
        error "!@"
    fi
    }
resize(){
    cd img
    if [ "$set" == 'W' ]; then
        for i in *.png
        do
            echo "Convirtiendo $i"
            convert "$i" -resize "$pixel"x "{$i%.*}_.png"
        done
    elif [ "$set" == 'H' ]; then
        for i in *.png
        do
            echo "Convirtiendo $i"
            convert "$i" -resize x$pixel "{$i%.*}_.png"
        done
    fi
    cd ..
}
error(){
    echo "Algo salió mal."
}
mensajes "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado así?

`convert "$i" -resize x$h "{$i%*}_.png"`

Es como suelo hacerlo yo, acabo de probarlo y funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Sí, ya ayer encontré la solución con x$h y para width uso "$h"x